# Use foreach to grab all but the last key, value pairs

Tags: php

I have a form with a lot of radio buttons and then a hidden field at the end.

I am looping through all of the input values to put them into an INSERT like this :

```
$count=count($_POST);
$counter=0;
$queryV="INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `value` ) VALUES ";
$sku = $_POST['number'];  //this is the one value coming from a hidden input

    foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
        if ($counter < $count -1 )
        $queryV.= "('$sku', '$value'),";
        elseif ($counter = $count -1 )
        $queryV.= "('$sku', '$value');";
        $counter++; 
    }
```

I am going to use the `$key` for a separate `INSERT` to a different table but my problem here is that final hidden input I dont want in the `$queryV` I need all of the values except the last `$_POST`

What I have here gives me something like :

```
INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `sku`, `data` ) VALUES ('12595200010037', 'yes'),('12595200010037', '12595200010037');
```

This is in an example where only one radio button was selected.  In such a situation I would want it to only return that one `$sku, $value` pair.  I never want the last `$key, $value` that comes from this `foreach`.  So I would want to see this :

```
INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `sku`, `data` ) VALUES ('12595200010037', 'yes');
```

Comment: `elseif ($counter = $count -1 )` --  did you mean ``elseif ($counter == $count -1 )``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe i did not understood question, however from my point of view:

```
$queryV = "INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `value` ) VALUES ";
$sku = $_POST['number'];
array_pop($_POST);
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) 
{
    $values[] = "('$sku', '$value')";
    // use $key for another query
}
$queryV .= implode(', ', $values) . ';';
```

Answer (score 0):

Should **$counter** start from one ?

```
$counter=1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that skip the first element, instead of the last one?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the first element will be skipped based on ($counter < $count -1 )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to build a query and skip the last key/value pair in the array. You have the line `elseif ($counter = $count -1 )`. First of all, that should be `==`, but maybe that's a typo introduced here and not in your actual code. Second, when `$counter == $count-1` that's actually the last item, not the next-to-last item.* To skip the last item, just change it to `$counter == $count-2`.

* Why? Because the array index starts from 0 but the count of items in your array starts from 1. For example, if an array has four elements, the array has length 4 and the elements are at indices 0, 1, 2, and 3. The next-to-last element is at index 2.

Answer (score 0):

look at array_pop http://uk.php.net/array_pop

So basically before heading into your loop call `array_pop($_POST)`.
That said you shouldn't really modify superglobals (IMHO) so you'd probably be looking at:

```
$postedData = $_POST; 
array_pop($postedData);
foreach ($postedData as $key => $value) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this function:

```
function insert(  )
{       
    $args = func_get_args();

    $table = $args[0];
    unset( $args[0] );

    $return = true;

    foreach( $args as $set )
    {
        $columns = implode( '`,`', array_keys( $set ) );
        $values = implode( "','", array_values( $set ) );
        $return =& query( "INSERT INTO {$table} (`{$columns}`) VALUES ('{$values}')" );
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Then in your code use:

```
$data = Array(
    'key1' => $value1,
    'key2' => $value2
);
insert('table', $data);
```

For your actual solution, you would use:

```
$data = $_POST;
array_pop($data); //Removes the last element in the array

insert('table', $data);
```